# How can I operate on grouped arrays from nested pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a series of nested pandas DataFrames containing several (hundreds) of arrays and I would like to average each variable across different nesting levels.

The variable `mydatadf` contains a very simple representative example of my actual data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydata = dict()
participant = ['participantA', 'participantB']
for p in participant:
    ses = dict()
    session = ['ses_1', 'ses_2']
    for s in session:
        series = dict()
        set = ['s_1', 's_2', 's_3']
        for se in set:
            reps = dict()
            rep = ['r_1', 'r_2', 'r_3', 'r_4', 'r_5']
            for r in rep:
                vars = dict()
                vars = {'var1': np.sin(np.random.rand(1000)*2),
                        'var2': np.sin(np.random.rand(1000)*2)}
                varsdf = pd.DataFrame(data=vars)
                reps[r] = vars
            series[se] = reps
        ses[s] = series
    mydata[p] = ses
mydatadf = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
```

How could I effectively average (for example) `var1` across the nesting levels `reps`, `series`, `ses` and/or `participant`?

Eventually, I would like to plot all `var1` objects and highlight with different colours averaged data across any desired nesting level.

```
for p in mydatadf.keys():
    for ses in mydatadf[p].keys():
        for set in mydatadf[p][ses].keys():
            for rep in mydatadf[p][ses][set].keys():
                data = mydatadf[p][ses][set][rep]['var1']
                plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: to keep it simple. why cant you create a dataframe and then plot it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always flatten the dataframe and do standard groupby operations (I don't know if it is optimal, but it works):

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(mydata)   #this will give a nested dataframe
df_flat = pd.DataFrame(df.T.index.str.split('.').tolist()).assign(values=df.T.values)


df_flat.head(3)
>>   0      1    2    3     4  \
0  participantA  ses_1  s_1  r_1  var1   
1  participantA  ses_1  s_1  r_1  var2   
2  participantA  ses_1  s_1  r_2  var1   

                                              values  
0  [0.7267196257553268, 0.9822775511169437, 0.991...  
1  [0.6633676714415264, 0.2823588336690545, 0.977...  
2  [0.2211576389168905, 0.9399581790280525, 0.645...
```

**Edit**: to groupby and apply a function (say, mean):

```
# in this case I choose column 4, corresponding to 'var'.
# You can change the name of the column using df_flat.columns.rename
# note that I use np.hstack as you are dealing with a an array of arrays
column = 4   
df_flat.groupby(column)['Values'].apply(lambda x: np.hstack(x).mean())
>> 4
var1    0.707803
var2    0.707821
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks a bit simpler. Would it be possible to elaborate a bit more your answer with an example of `groupby.mean()` operation on `var1`?

Comment: I am particularly interested (and stuck) in averaging the 1D array of `values` across other levels (i.e. participant, ses, or rep) so that I can get a mean `value` array across conditions.

Comment: It's the same, just change the value of `column` to 0, 1, 2 or 3. Is it not working?

Comment: It does compute the average, but it provides the mean of everything (i.e. a single value). In my data, `values` contains an array of length 1000, and what I want is to average across levels the whole array, obtaining an averaged array with length 1000

Comment: In that case you can vertically stack the data: replace `np.hstack(x).mean()` with `np.vstack(x).mean(axis=0)`. Is that the output you are looking for?